# Can I pass additional arguments into a scipy bvp function or boundary conditions? / SciPy questions from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm working on converting a code that solves a BVP (Boundary Value Problem) from MATLAB to Python (SciPy). However, I'm having a little bit of trouble. I wanted to pass a few arguments into the function and the boundary conditions; so in MATLAB, it's something like:

```
solution =    bvp4c(@(x,y)fun(x,y,args),@(ya,yb)boundarycond(ya,yb,arg1,args),solinit);
```

Where arg1 is a value, and args is a structure or a class instance. So I've been trying to do this on scipy, and the closest I get to is something like:

```
solBVP = solve_bvp(func(x,y,args), boundC(x,y,arg1,args), x, y)
```

But then it errors out saying that y is not defined (which it isn't, because it's the vector of first order DEs).

Has anyone tried to pass additional arguments into solve_bvp? If so, how did you manage to do it? I have a workaround right now essentially putting args and arg1 as global variables, but that seems incredibly sketchy if I want to make this code somewhat modular.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome to SO! Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I haven't used this particular `solve`, but most spell out carefully what arguments the object  function should accept.  They also have an `args` tuple for extra arguments.

Comment: according to the [matlab docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html) solinit is obtained via bvpinit, which itself accepts two arguments, the original x-mesh, and the y-guesses corresponding to the x-mesh pnodes. This is what the [solve_bvp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html) function seems to expect as well. Also, I don't know if what you wrote was meant as pseudocode, but if it wasn't, then presumably that's not how you're supposed to call solve_bvp. "func" and "boundC" need to be callables (just like in matlab).

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by wrapping it in a larger function, thank you for your help